# How can I set up a language filter for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

My brother on the east coast recently got my family into Minecraft.

There's only one catch to us really enjoying playing with him on his favorite public server:  Foul language.

Several of the players on this server swear casually and this is something I'm not exposing my family to. Right now we're playing on a server I set up on my LAN but would like to play on my brother's server if we can.

How can I set up a language filter for Minecraft?

Comment: it's probably easier to set up a whitelist and block everyone else... but I don't know how to setup either, sorry

Comment: Do you control the server? If not, bad luck.

Comment: I would think you could get a mod for your jar that could filter it. Surprisingly, though, I can't find one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Question comes down to is it textual language, or spoken? If it's textual then I'm sure it's possible!  [This](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/keepitclean) mod will solve the issue. That is if you can get the admins on the server to install it.

If it's spoken, I either suggest asking them to play without sound either via minecraft it's self or the client being used. I don't know how to do this though. As a heads up, the two main VoiP (?) services are *mumble* and *teamspeak*.

Comment: It's all textual.

Comment: Then the bukkit plugin will work.

Comment: @Kalamane is this the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are many mods and (Bukkit) plugins that support filtering; some very simple, and in some you can define the words you want to filter. Visit a full list of Bukkit plugins [here](http://plugins.bukkit.org).