# my minecraft is unable to show coordinates and im using windows 8 dell computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i press F3 and it brings up everything except coordinates.Ive tried to start mine craft 1.8 but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably enabled Reduced Debug Info. Open the pause menu and go to "Options..." and then "Chat Settings...". Click the button that reads "Reduced Dedug Info" to change the value from ON to OFF and you should be able to see the coordinates.

[image]

Image borrowed from [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184339/133553).